# Is there any way I can set a number of times somethings loops in batch file

Tags: batch-file

Here is my code I want to know if I can set a number of times it loops

```
@echo off
:IDK
color a
:loop
echo derp
color 1a
echo derp
color 2a
echo derp
color 3a
echo derp
color 4a
echo derp
color 5a
echo derp
color 6a
echo derp
color 7a
echo derp
color 8a
echo derp
goto loop
```

Comment: Take a look in [Microsoft's for command documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/for.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `FOR /L` loop:

```
SET NumberOfTimes=10
FOR /L %%A IN (1,1,%NumberOfTimes%) DO (
    REM Enter code to repeat here.
)
```